# Git2go: After CreateCommit() all files appear like being added for deletion

Tags: git, go, commit

With git2go I do a AddAll() and a CreateCommit() on a newly cloned directory. The Push() works fine and I get all commited files, when I clone the remote to a different place. But if I call `git status` in the first directory then I get:

(sorry for the German, and I don't have the correct translation, it means the branch is at the same position as origin/master, `'gelöscht'` means `'deleted'` and `'Unbeobachtete dateien'` means `'unwatched files'`)

```
Auf Branch master
Ihr Branch ist auf dem selben Stand wie 'origin/master'.
zum Commit vorgemerkte Änderungen:
  (benutzen Sie "git reset HEAD <Datei>..." zum Entfernen aus der Staging-Area)

    gelöscht:               .gitignore
    gelöscht:               html/.gitignore
    gelöscht:               images/.gitignore
    gelöscht:               json/.gitignore
    gelöscht:               pjs/.gitignore
    gelöscht:               pjs/test37.pjs
    gelöscht:               pjs/test37.png
    gelöscht:               sounds/.gitignore

Unbeobachtete Dateien:
  (benutzen Sie "git add <Datei>...", um die Änderungen zum Commit vorzumerken)

    .gitignore
    html/
    images/
    json/
    pjs/
    sounds/
```

What I would expect is the following:

> ```
> Nothing to commit. No files changed. (or similar)
> ```

My code:

```
 // Add
repo, err := git.OpenRepository(dir)
index, err := repo.Index()
err = index.AddAll([]string{}, git.IndexAddDefault, nil)
treeId, err := index.WriteTreeTo(repo)
tree, err := repo.LookupTree(treeId)

// Commit
sig := &git.Signature{
    Name:  userName,
    Email: userName + "@" + beego.AppConfig.String("userdata::emailserver"),
    When:  time.Now(),
}
commitId, err := repo.CreateCommit("HEAD", sig, sig, message, tree)

// Push
remote, err := repo.LookupRemote("origin")    
err = remote.Push([]string{"refs/heads/master"}, nil, sig, message)
```

(I took all error handling out, to make it shorter)

Comment: You're creating a tree from the index, but are you writing the index itself?

Comment: Yes, that was it. index.Write() was missing. Now it works. You want to put that as an answer?

Comment: Sure - unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with go, so please let me know if I'm mistaken about something.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening the current repository's index:

```
index, err := repo.Index()
```

And you are mutating it, and creating a new tree that you subsequently create a commit from:

```
err = index.AddAll([]string{}, git.IndexAddDefault, nil)
treeId, err := index.WriteTreeTo(repo)
```

Unlike the `git add` command line, `AddAll` did not write the index back to disk.  This functionality allows you to use the index as a data structure without actually staging the changes immediately.  (Many libgit2 functions like merge and rebase use the index as a generic data structure that you can continue to modify or convert to a tree.)

Thus, at this point, all the changes to the index remain in-memory.  You must explicitly write the index back to disk if you want to persist your changes:

```
index.Write()
```